# Using Lambda / Linq Filter Parent Collection based on Child Items

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

I have the following two classes;

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public int Code {get;set;}
    public int SupplierId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

I have a List of Orders, and each order contains a number of different items.    I am wanting to filter the Order List, so that I can achieve the following;

- Return all orders where at least 1 item in the Item List has SupplierId = 1
- Don't return any orders if no items match SupplierId = 1

**UPDATE**

How can I expand the results as well so that I only return orders and Items that have SupplierId = 1

This is what I tried so far which now works.  But how can I compact it further;

```
 List<Order> OrderList = new List<Order>();

 foreach(Order order in Order.Get(1))
 {
     Order tmpOrder = order;
     tmpOrder.Items = order.Items.Where(x => x.SupplierId == 1).ToList();

     if (tmpOrder.Items.Count > 0)
         OrderList.Add(tmpOrder );
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you had with your attempted solutions?  Each step of your requirements maps pretty much exactly, word for word, to a LINQ operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Return all orders where at least 1 item in the Item List has SupplierId = 1
>
> Don't return any orders if no items match SupplierId = 1

```
IEnuemrable<Order> orders = //...

var supplierOrders = orders.where(o => o.Items.Any(i => i.SupplierId == 1))
  .ToList();
```

Seems pretty straight forward.  Unless you mean return ALL orders if ANY order has a supplierId of 1.

**Update 1**

> How can I expand the results as well so that I only return orders and Items that have SupplierId = 1

EF currently (to my knowledge up to EF6) does not allow you to do this in a single query.  It is still very easy and actually performant in consideration to the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) problem EF faces (sometimes).

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{ 
  DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
  DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
|

// each of these orders do not contain any
// items, we did not .Include() them.
var supplierOrders = db.Orders
  .Where(o => o.Items
               .Any(i => i.SupplierId == 1))
  .ToList();

var orderIds = supplierOrders
  .Select(so => so.Id)
  .ToList();

var supplierItems = db.Items.
  .Where(i => orderIds.Contain(i.SupplierId))
  .ToList();
```

Because we're using EF Context, it automatically will wire up any items the contact caches locally to any associated item as long as you have the correct relationships setup in EF (which I would recommend doing).

Comment: Only want to return Orders that contain Items with Supplierid = 1.

Comment: That is exactly what this does.

Comment: Or do you mean you want Orders that contain Items with SupplierId and only the Items with SupplierId = 1.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.  Only orders that have SupplierId matching 1.  You can see my code I tried so for with foreach loop which works

Comment: Make sure that in the future you spell out **exactly** what you are looking for.